# How do I work with an array object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have a Laravel site I am modifying, but there are some parts of the PHP code I don't quite understand, which are "array objects" or "object arrays". You see, I don't even know what to call them and so can't find a tutorial or basic data on it. Below is the code that I am dealing with:

```
 private function parseMetric($result, $view)
    {
        $data = collect([]);

        $result->each(function($item) use ($data, $view) {
            if (isset($item->metric->{$view})) {
                $data->push((object)[
                    'label' => $item->metric->{$view},
                    'value' => $item->metric->count
                ]);
            }
        });
...
```

From what I can tell, this creates an object out of $result. If I json_encode this and echo it out I get this:

```
 [{"label":"1k-25k","value":14229},
{"label":"1mm+","value":1281},
{"label":"25k-50k","value":398},
{"label":"50k-75k","value":493},
{"label":"75k-100k","value":3848},
{"label":"100k-150k","value":9921},
{"label":"150k-200k","value":4949},
{"label":"200k-250k","value":3883},
{"label":"250k-300k","value":2685},
{"label":"300k-350k","value":2744},
{"label":"350k-500k","value":4526},
{"label":"500k-1mm","value":8690}]
```

Now this is obviously an array of arrays... or is it? Is it an array of objects? Or is it an object containing arrays? But the most important question is, how do I access and move or change the individual objects/arrays in this object? For example, I want to take the second object/array, which is:

```
{"label":"1mm+","value":1281}
```

and move it to the end. How do I do that? How do I find it? I used the following piece of code to find it which is pretty clunky:

```
$pos = strpos(json_encode($result), '1mm+');
        if($pos){
            Log::debug('Enrich 73, I found it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
        }
```

And once I find it, how do I move that array/object to the end of the whole object?

And finally, where can I find some kind of tutorial, or documentation, that describes this construct and how to work with it?

Comment: What is `collect`?

Comment: @deceze `collect` is the function that laravel provides for creating collections.

Comment: You're not helping yourself by working with JSON, which just complicates the matter. Use `var_dump` if you need to inspect your data, don't confuse yourself by converting to an entirely different representation where you need to understand the translation.

Comment: Converting to json was the only way I was able to see what was in $result. How else do I do that? That's part of what I'm asking - how do I access values? Doing a var_dump within a Controller results in '[]'.

Comment: Ah, using the Laravel 'dump()' construct got me a better view. However it still looks the same and I still don't know how to access individual elements. $result[1] gives an error. $result->label[1] gives an error.

Comment: You can use `dd($result)`, or "Dump and Die", anywhere in a Controller to print something out and end execution. Super useful for trying to debug things. Can you add the output of that to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to `json_encode` the `data`. Since the data is an instance of [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections), you can manipulate it like so

```
$item = $data->firstWhere('label', '1mm+'); // get the item
$data = $data->filter(fn($value, $key) => $value->label !== '1mm+') // remove $item from $data
             ->push($item); // move $item to the end of data
```

Comment: This gives an error on the "$filtered = ..." line: ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @DavidN, I've updated my code. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: it worked!! Thank you. One question. I tried to write 'dump($item)' to my log, but got the error, "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". How do I dump out the value of $item?

Comment: Yes `$item` is an object so you can access its props like `$item->label`, etc. Use `dd($item)` instead of dump($item).

Comment: Using dd($item) sometimes doesn't work because a lot of the pages are loaded by datatables. Thaks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to Laravel documnentation for Collections, you can try something like this :

To find index of element with name = "1mm+" :

```
$index = $datas->search(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['name'] == "1mm+";
});
```

to get an element at a given index :
`$element = $datas->get($index);`

to Move element at index 3 to the end :

```
$index = 3 
$elementToMove = $data->splice($index, 1);
$datas->push($elementToMove);
```

Here is a link to the document used : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: This gives an error, "ERROR: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" on the 'return $item['name'] == "1mm+";' line